# Python: How to obtain current bandwidth usage?

Tags: python

I need to get current bandwidth usage on given interface in my Python code. How can I achieve this?

I tried to extract the value from `/proc/net/dev` twice with short sleep interval (e.g. 0.3s) between two consecutive calls and compute the difference in bytes divided by time. It works but I do not know if I can trust this results. I'm looking for some more elegant solutions. Any tools, libraries, or simple algorithms?

I will appreciate all suggestions!

Comment: you mean like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573681/python-getting-upload-download-speeds/26853086#26853086

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are libraries for this, like [PSutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil), but if you are on *Nix I would opt for using the underlying system.

Although you could use `/proc/net/dev`, rather use `/sys/class/net/eth0/statistics` since you will not have to parse anything since there are individual files for each statistic